# persian phone number regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new in programming. I want to implement phone number validation using javascript in my website. I want some regex with conditions below:

- a digit with length of 11
- it should start with 09
- no any string or space in the input is accepted

e.g.

1. "09131234455" // is accepted
2. "091 05488963" // not accepted

thanks anyone can help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `^09\d{9}$` (first '09', then 9 digits, all this surrounded with
"start of string" and "end of string" anchors).